# An example for $m^{*}(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) \ne \lim_{k \to \infty} m^{*}(A_k)$?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples, outer-measure

It's a theorem that

> Let $(X, M, m)$ be a measure space and let $\{A_k\}$ be a sequence of measurable sets. If $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset\dots$ and $m(A_N)<\infty$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ then $m(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} m(A_k)$.

I was wondering if measurablity of $\{A_k\}$ is a must or *is there an example* of non-measurable $\{A_k\}$ such that $m^{*}(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) \ne \lim_{k \to \infty} m^{*}(A_k)$ even if for each $k$,  $m^{*}(A_k) < \infty$?

Comment: @user10354138, No!

Comment: Did you actually study David's answer?

Comment: @user10354138, my question doesn't suppose $\cap E_n=\emptyset$ and not necessarily $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \mu^*(E_n) =0$

Comment: You asked for an example, and David's answer is one.

Comment: @user10354138, I didn't understand David's answer at all! For starters, is $C$ actually Vitali's set? $\mu^*(E_n) =\mu^*(h_n+C)$ is true because $H$ is countable? All $\mu^*(E_n)>0$ doesn't imply $\lim \mu^*(E_n)>0$ so how contradiction?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: @user10354138  There are simpler examples than the one presented by David. Take a look in my answer below.

Comment: @L.G. The set $C$ mentioned by David Ullrich in the link is a Vitali set.

Answer (score 1):

> *is there an example* of non-measurable $\{A_k\}$ such that $m^{*}(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) \ne \lim_{k \to \infty} m^{*}(A_k)$ even if for each $k$,  $m^{*}(A_k) < \infty$?

The answer is YES. Here is a simple example.

Let $(\Bbb N, \Sigma, m)$ be a measure space where $\Sigma =\{\emptyset, \Bbb N\}$ and $m$ is a measure defined as $m(\emptyset)=0$ and $m(\Bbb N)=1$.

It is easy to see that, $m^*(\emptyset)=0$ and, for all $E \subseteq \Bbb N$, if $E\neq \emptyset$, then $m^*(E)=1$.

For each $k \in \Bbb N$, let $A_k=\{k, k+1, k+2, \cdots \} \subseteq \Bbb N$.

We have $\bigcap_k A_k = \emptyset$. So, we have
$$m^*\left (\bigcap_k A_k \right) = m^*(\emptyset)= 0 $$

and, for each $k \in \Bbb N$, $A_k \neq \emptyset$. So, $m^*(A_k)=1$. So, we have
$$m^*\left (\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \right) =0 \ne 1= \lim_{k \to \infty} m^{*}(A_k)$$

Comment: Thank you very much! :)